# Print spooler needs resetting often

Tags: windows-7, printing

This only seems to happen on my bosses laptop. Every other day or so I have to reset the print spooler service before it will allow him to print anything. Is there a way to fix this?

**Windows 7 Pro laptop**

Comment: Printer make/model?  Have you updated the drivers to the latest?

Comment: Is it a HP/Compaq? They released a patch via HP update recently for print spooling issues.

Comment: We've seen that a lot with low-end HP printers and Windows 7.  Very annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest removing all printer drivers and only use the ones you need. The best way is via the Print Management MMC (start > run > mmc > Add/Remove Snap in > Print Management > Add the local server > next next next etc etc).

Once that's done, stop your Printer Spooler service via the services.mmc and then expand the Print Management list until the Drivers appear and in the right hand pane rght click on a driver and choose 'Remove Driver Package'.

Reboot and then install the driver you need.